# Jekyll: Filter posts by subdirectory

Tags: github, jekyll

I'm using jekyll to host a website on github.io

The homepage has a "Recent Posts" section which displays the latest 10 posts.

I'm using the following code in my index.html to generate the list:

```
<ul class="post-list">
{% for post in site.posts limit:10 %} 
  <li><article><a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }} <span class="entry-date"><time datetime="{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}">{{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}</time></span>{% if post.excerpt %} <span class="excerpt">{{ post.excerpt }}</span>{% endif %}</a></article></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The _posts directory has 3 subdirectories.  The above code generates a list from all three directories.  I want to exclude the posts in one of those directories in my "Recent Posts" directory.

More generally, how can I select a subset of the subdirectories in the _posts directory?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding an *if* statement inside the for loop:

```
{% if post.path contains 'xxx' or post.path contains 'yyy'%}
  <li><article>...</article></li>
{% endif %}
```

This works for simple cases but it could get ugly for more complicated cases.

The *for* loop seems to be iterating over a list but I can't figure out how to generate a list with the elements I want.  I can't find a good reference for the scripting language used by Jekyll.